# How to compute stable / unstable manifolds when eigenvectors have both non-zero x and y components

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, bifurcation

In class I was taught to compute stable/unstable manifolds as done in the following example:

We have the dynamical system:
$$
\dot{x} = x-xy 
$$
$$
\dot{y} = -y+x^2
$$

We are interested in the manifolds for the fixed point $(0,0)$. We find the Jacobian to be:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}1-y&-x\\2x&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

Evaluating the Jacobian at the origin gives

$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

Thus, we get the eigenvalue $\lambda_+ = 1$ with associated eigenvector $(1,0)$ and the eigenvalue $\lambda_+ = -1$ with associated eigenvector $(0,1)$.

Thus, we have $E^s = \text{span}${$(0,1)$} = { $x=0$} $= y-$axis and $E^u = \text{span}${$(1,0)$} = {$y = 0$} = x-axis.

Due to symmetry of the system, the stable manifold just be the y-axis. For the unstable manifold, we let $y = g(x)$ since $y \in E^s$ and $x \in E^u$. We then observe that $\dot{y} = \dot{x}g'(x)$. We know $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ from our original system and so we get

$$
-y+x^2 = (x-xy)g'(x)  
$$

But on the manifold $y = g(x)$ and so we get

$$
-g(x) + x^2 = (x-xy)g'(x)
$$

We then try a taylor series expansion for $g(x)$ as $g(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \dots$ and substitute this into our equation. We can then match coefficients to whatever degree we want.

However I don't know how to do this if the eigenvectors aren't so nice. If we don't have eigenvectors of the form $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, then the stable/unstable manifolds will not just be on the x or y axis, and will instead have both x and y components. So then I can't let $y=g(x)$ as was done in the example above.

How do we deal with this?

A question I have come across where this occurs is:

$$
\dot{x} = -2x -3y -x^2
$$
$$
\dot{y}= x + 2y + xy -3y^2
$$

In this case I get $E^u = $ span{$(1,-1)$} and $E^u = $ span{$(3,-1)$}. I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do exactly the same, set for the first direction $y(x)=x(-1+v(x))$ and insert into the quotient
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+2x(-1+v)+x^2(-1+v)-3x^2(-1+v)^2}{-2x-3x(-1+v)-x^2}
\\
=\frac{-1+2v-x+xv-3x(1-2v+v^2)}{1-3v-x}
\\
=-1+\frac{-v-2x+xv-3x(1-v)^2}{1-3v-x}
\\
=-1+v+xv'
$$
Isolating $v'$ gives
$$
xv'=\frac{-2v-5x +3v^2+8xv-3xv^2}{1-3v-x}
$$
Inserting a power series $v(x)=v_1x+v_2x^2+...$ gives
$$
1-(3v_1+1)x-3v_2x^2-...)(v_1+2v_2x+3v_3x^2+...)
\\= -5-2(v_1+v_2xv_3x^2+...)+8x(v_1+v_2x+..)
   \\ +3x(v_1^2+2v_1v_2x+...)-3x^2(v_1^2+2v_1v_2x+...)
$$
Comparing coefficients gets $v_1=-\frac53$
$$
2v_2-v_1(3v_1+1)=-2v_2+8v_1+3v_1^2\\
4v_2=v_1(9+6v_1)=-\frac53(9-10)=\frac53
$$
etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'm unfamiliar with the method you used. Is this equivalent to what I would ordinarily do (as shown in my question)? In mine I have $\dot{y} = \dot{x}g'(x)$, so I guess I could rewrite that as $\frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}} = g'(x)$ which is more like how you've written it. But then you already have a form for $g(x)$ which I wouldn't normally have - what makes you set $y(x) = x(-1+v(x))$ initially? Also, since you have $g(x) = x(-1+v(x))$, then when you rearrange to find $v'$, the LHS is $g'$ right? ** Edit: Ive just understood that the last line of the first section of working is $g'$.

Comment: I think my question just boils down to: how do you know to do $y = x(1-v(x))$. Why not just have $y = v(x)$? Thanks

Comment: You could do that too. Then the first terms of the power series expansion reduce to the eigenvalue equation. But as you have solved that already, you can insert these values, the coordinates of the eigenvectors, directly. The idea is that the eigenvectors define a line, and the subspace is a perturbation of the line. In some cases it will be preferable or the only possibility to set $x=u(y)$, especially if the eigenvector is on the $y$-axis.

Comment: Thank you. Also since both eigenvectors have non-zero x and y components, instead of doing $y=g(x)$, could I also have used $x = g(y)$?

Comment: Yes. The solutions are then obviously related by power series inversion.